# Java and Ruby: "everything is an object" in OO?

Tags: java, ruby, object

Is everything in Java an object, the way it is in Ruby?

Books, tutorials, everything states "everything in Ruby is an object", but is that common for object oriented languages?

Is everything an object is Java as well, or is object oriented just a paradigm of programming, and it doesn't mean that everything is or evaluates to an object?

Comment: FWIW not everything in Ruby is an object, but values are. Things like "if" are not.

Comment: 'Object-oriented' seems to have as many meanings as there are people to ask, or more. Strange, as it was quite precisely defined by Peter Wegner in OOPSLA as long ago as 1987.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

As far as *values* go, the "primitive types" (`int`, `bool`, `float`, etc.) in Java are *not* objects. In Ruby they are objects. (In some Ruby implementations fixnums are "value types" internally for performance, but externally they are treatable as "real" objects that have methods).

In addition, there are other things that are objects in Ruby that are not objects in Java such as classes. (Actually, Java exposes these as `Class` as well, but in a different sense.)

There are some things that are not objects in either language, such as *variables* and *methods*. (Although in Ruby it is easy to get an object that represents a given method.)

Anyway, I think the bigger picture is that the [Object Oriented programming paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_oriented) presents a *way* to group data and operations on said data. (This is generally done through *instance methods*, as in Java and Ruby, although it might also be done through *multiple dispatch* and other languages, like Haskell which is "non-OO", offer alternative approaches to this task.)

Often times the definition of "OO" also includes "inheritance", "encapsulation", "abstraction", and other silly textbook terms, but the usage and patterns of different "OO" languages can vary greatly and overlap those found in "non-OO" languages ;-)

Comment: Methods are sort of objects: `Object.instance_method(:to_s)`. For example: `Object.instance_method(:to_s).bind([]).call` is not the same as `[].to_s` even though both are invoking *a* `to_s` method on `[]`. Though I'm not entirely sure if this really "counts" as providing methods are objects—perhaps just that they *can* be.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Indeed. Methods can be represented by objects rather readily in Ruby and `instance_method` gets the method-object representing the *message* `:to_s` for the given class... I am not sure how the different implementations work these days, however, as to how the methods are handled internally. (This aspect of Ruby -- "message passing" -- works in contrast to JavaScript or Python in which methods are really *first-class* function-objects that are resolved up before being invoked.)

Comment: Right, and of course Java in which methods can never be treated as objects, and so instead you have odd things like anonymous classes which contain methods (usually with name requirements for the given context). Personally I think Java's anonymous classes are a horrible substitute for lambdas.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I'll just follow that up with "I do my best to avoid Java" ;-)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm "primitives", such as `int` and `bool`, in Java do not have methods (at all); there are corresponding non-primitive wrapping types like `Integer` and `Boolean` that do. In C# "value types" (including `int` and `bool`) can *still* have methods and *still* derive from `object`, although they have limitations and different semantics then their "reference type" counterparts. Neither C# or Java support "expando" (or singleton methods) added to existing objects. (Although there is deep magic that can be worked with dynamic bytecode manipulation/creation in the JVM/CLR runtimes.)