# Everything's an object in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and heard a lot that everything is an object in Scala. What I don't get is what's the advantage of "everything's an object"? What are things that I cannot do if everything is not an object? Examples are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Ruby is very common to Scala in this aspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158791/java-and-ruby-everything-is-an-object-in-oo

Comment: Somebody who knows Scala should write an answer about the usefulness of function objects, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of having "everything" be an object is that you have far fewer cases where abstraction breaks.

For example, methods are not objects in Java.  So if I have two strings, I can

```
String s1 = "one";
String s2 = "two";
static String caps(String s) { return s.toUpperCase(); }
caps(s1);  // Works
caps(s2);  // Also works
```

So we have abstracted away string identity in our operation of making something upper case.  But what if we want to abstract away the identity of the operation--that is, we do *something* to a String that gives back another String but we want to abstract away what the details are?  Now we're stuck, because methods aren't objects in Java.

In Scala, methods can be converted to *functions*, which are objects.  For instance:

```
def stringop(s: String, f: String => String) = if (s.length > 0) f(s) else s
stringop(s1, _.toUpperCase)
stringop(s2, _.toLowerCase)
```

Now we have abstracted the idea of performing some string transformation on nonempty strings.

And we can make lists of the operations and such and pass them around, if that's what we need to do.

There are other less essential cases (object vs. class, primitive vs. not, value classes, etc.), but the big one is collapsing the distinction between method and object so that passing around and abstracting over functionality is just as easy as passing around and abstracting over data.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage is that you don't have different operators that follow different rules within your language.  For example, in Java to perform operations involving objects, you use the `dot name` technique of calling the code (static objects still use the `dot name` technique, but sometimes the `this object` or the `static object` is inferred) while built-in items (not objects) use a different method, that of built-in operator manipulation.

```
Number one = Integer.valueOf(1);
Number two = Integer.valueOf(2);
Number three = one.plus(two); // if only such methods existed.

int one = 1;
int two = 2;
int three = one + two;
```

the main differences is that the `dot name` technique is subject to polymorphisim, operator overloading, method hiding, and all the good stuff that you can do with Java objects.  The `+` technique is predefined and completely not flexible.

Scala circumvents the inflexibility of the `+` method by basically handling it as a `dot name` operator, and defining a strong one-to-one mapping of such operators to *object methods*.  Hence, in Scala *everything is an object* means that *everything* is an object, so the operation

```
 5 + 7
```

results in two objects being created (a 5 object and a 7 object) the plus method of the 5 object being called with the parameter 7 (if my scala memory serves me correctly) and a "12" object being returned as the value of the `5 + 7` operation.

This everything is an object has a lot of benefits in a functional programming environment, for example, blocks of code now are object too, making it possible to pass back and forth blocks of code (without names) as parameters, yet still be bound to strict type checking (the block of code only returns `Long` or a subclass of `String` or whatever).

When it boils down to it, it makes some kinds of solutions very easy to implement, and often the inefficiencies are mitigated by the lack of need to handle "move into primitives, manipulate, move out of primitives" marshalling code.

Comment: This has much more to do with allowing arbitrary symbolic characters as method names that it does with everything-is-an-object.  In fact, primitives are _not_ precisely objects for performance reasons, though Scala does a very, very good job at covering up the boxing that it does (and only boxing when necessary).

Comment: How it is done is a technique, the viewpoint is that what is promoted by the "everything is an object".  Just like compiled Java is not assembly instructions, even when the implementation technique _turns them into compiled assembly instructions_ (aka JIT).

Comment: Nonetheless, Java cannot define a `+` method _on anything_, whereas it can define a `plus` method on objects.  It's the allowed identifiers in a symbol, not the everything-is-an-objectness, that makes Scala distinct here.

Comment: I understood your example just fine.  But the example is more misleading than illuminating.  `+` could be a reserved symbol defined only on built-in number types _and everything would still be an object_.  The example completely misses the essence of the distinction.  Although you mention genuine benefits later, this does not outweigh the focus on what is really just lack-of-permissive-naming in Java.

Comment: Java already boxes and unboxes primitives as if it wants everything to be an object.  It's just not very good at it.  More telling is what are not objects at all: static methods (can't get a static method via inheritance), methods (can't pass around as objects), constructors.  If you do want to show how bad Java is at making primitives look like objects, try `5.toString();`.  That's one of the canonical `Object` methods, and it doesn't work.  That's about as clear as it gets that `5` is not an object.

Comment: I still think you're missing much but not all of the point, but I am not sure I can explain it any better than I already have.  You keep making points that don't address the key Scala/Java difference.  For example, note that you can't inherit from `Int` in Scala either, so good luck with your "object-oriented polymorphism".  Anyway, I'm sure anyone reading the comments has plenty of material to use to make up their own mind.

Answer (score 3):

One specific advantage that comes to my mind (since you asked for examples) is what in Java are primitive types (`int, boolean ...`) , in Scala are objects that you can add functionality to with implicit conversions. For example, if you want to add a `toRoman` method to ints, you could write an implicit class like:

```
implicit class RomanInt(i:Int){
  def toRoman = //some  algorithm to convert i to a Roman representation
}
```

Then, you could call this method from any `Int` literal like :

```
val romanFive = 5.toRoman  // V
```

This way you can 'pimp' basic types to adapt them to your needs

Comment: This is just as true whether `Int`s are objects, or whether you can create implicit conversions from primitives to classes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the points made by others, I always emphasize that the uniform treatment of all values in Scala is in part an illusion. For the most part it is a very welcome illusion. And Scala is very smart to use real JVM primitives as much as possible and to perform automatic transformations (usually referred to as boxing and unboxing) only as much as necessary.

However, if the dynamic pattern of application of automatic boxing and unboxing is very high, there can be undesirable costs (both memory and CPU) associated with it. This can be partially mitigated with the use of *specialization*, which creates special versions of generic classes when particular type parameters are of (programmer-specified) primitive types. This avoids boxing and unboxing but comes at the cost of more `.class` files in your running application.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is an object in Scala, though more things are objects in Scala than their analogues in Java.

The advantage of objects is that they're bags of state which also have some behavior coupled with them. With the addition of polymorphism, objects give you ways of changing the implicit behavior and state. Enough with the poetry, let's go into some examples.

The `if` statement is not an object, in either scala or java. If it were, you could be able to subclass it, inject another dependency in its place, and use it to do stuff like logging to a file any time your code makes use of the `if` statement. Wouldn't that be magical? It would in some cases help you debug stuff, and in other cases it would  make your hairs grow white before you found a bug caused by someone overwriting the behavior of `if`.

Visiting an objectless, statementful world: Imaging your favorite OOP programming language. Think of the standard library it provides. There's plenty of classes there, right? They offer ways for customization, right? They take parameters that are other objects, they create other objects. You can customize all of these. You have polymorphism. Now imagine that all the standard library was simply keywords. You wouldn't be able to customize nearly as much, because you can't overwrite keywords. You'd be stuck with whatever cases the language designers decided to implement, and you'd be helpless in customizing anything there. Such languages exist, you know them well, they're the sequel-like languages. You can barely create functions there, but in order to customize the behavior of the `SELECT` statement, new versions of the language had to appear which included the features most desired. This would be an extreme world, where you'd only be able to program by asking the language designers for new features (which you might not get, because someone else more important would require some feature incompatible with what you want)

In conclusion, NOT everything is an object in scala: Classes, expressions, keywords and packages surely aren't. More things however are, like functions. 
What's IMHO a nice rule of thumb is that more objects equals more flexibility

P.S. in Python for example, even more things are objects (like the classes themselves, the analogous concept for `packages` (that is python modules and packages). You'd see how there, black magic is easier to do, and that brings both good and bad consequences.