# In Scala EVERYTHING is an Object - are Classes Objects?

Tags: scala, class, oop, reflection

I recently ran into the scala.reflect.runtime API and tried to generate Classdefinitins by Stringevaluation.
Here is the aproach i made in the scala REPL:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime._

scala> val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
cm: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.n[....]

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.to[...]

scala> tb.eval(tb.parse("class A; scala.reflect.classTag[A].runtimeClass"))
res0: Any = class __wrapper$1$c6a9fb3f39c2499a9ff6e29384816f58.__wrapper$[...]
```

Since the answer by the REPL is not:

> defined class A

but

> res0: Any = class
>   __wrapper$1$c6a9fb3f39c2499a9ff6e29384816f58.__wrapper$[...]

I started to wonder if i actually created a class or kind of just initialized an abstract Any instance? 
I once read that in scala EVERYTHING is an object. If res0 in my REPL now actually holds a class, then this would mean, that even classes are objects in scala? But this is where i cant find any more input so im really confused. 
If classes are not objects in scala then what does res0 actually hold at this moment? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I already looked for similar questions like in [EntryLevelDevs Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669596/everythings-an-object-in-scala), but my specific questins is not answered. Its usualy only about functions being objects...

Comment: yes, classes are objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, classes are not objects in a strict sense, neither are methods. Scala runs on the JVM and Scala classes and methods compile down to the concepts of the JVM.

What is usually meant by "everything is an object" is every value is an object, i.e. native values, instances, functions.

However, there are objects that give you access to the meta information of classes and methods. If you do this

```
res0.getClass
```

You will see, that res0 is an instance of the (Java) class Class. So you just have gotten an object from the JVM reflection API.

The REPL does not give you a "defined class A" because you have defined it in an other context.

By the way, instead of `scala.reflect.classTag[A].runtimeClass` you could have just written `classOf[A]`.

Comment: "classes are not objects" ??? Does `.getClass` return not a class or not an object in your opinion?

Comment: It does not return a class, just a handle to a class. This might be a technical view on things. But for example, classes are serializable, but if you deserialize them, you just get a handle to a class of the same name. Also, on a language level, Scala does not really support this notion to see classes as objects. There is no type that really expresses, that an object represents a class with a certain interface (i.e. certain constructor arguments). This association of classOf[T] with T happens purely on a library level.

Comment: By that logic, a string is not an object either: `java.lang.String` "is not a string, just a handle to a string". This is not "a technical view on things", it is a _wrong_ view.

Comment: @dth I think I can see your point, but just think of it, isn't the handle for an object not an object as well? I agree that methods in scala are not objects, although functions are. Most of other things in scala are objects, however you can always find something that is not an object in any language.

Comment: You not being able to see what I mean, does not make it wrong. String really contains everything that makes a string a String. It does not have a the serialization issue. I do not have to call some library function on a string to be able to pass it around as object. Maybe I can put it an other way: there is no language support for classes as objects, only library support.

Comment: @dth, of course not. Your saying a wrong thing makes it wrong. It has nothing to do with what I can or cannot see. Ok, so now you are saying that an object must be `Serializable` in order to be considered an object by you, is that it? Is a jdbc `Connection` an object then? You cannot serialize that ...
And I can't begin to guess what you mean by "language support" as opposed to "library support".